# Stack traces with async/await

Tags: c#, logging, stack-trace, async-await, visual-studio-debugging

It's clear why stack traces are affected with Microsoft's new programming paradigm. We now have a semantic stack and a couple of physical ones (my choice of words).

What I get to see is an exception's `StackTrace` property (and in the debugger) is the physical ones, concatenated:

```
private async Task CheckFooAndBar()
{
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger("Test");
    log.Info("CheckFooAndBar");
    try
    {
        await Foo();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info("StackTrace of last exception: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
private async Task Foo()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    await Bar();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
}
private async Task Bar()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    throw new Exception();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
}
```

This gives:

```
StackTrace of last exception:    at NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Program.<Bar>d__d.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Console\Program.cs:line 53
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Program.<Foo>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Console\Program.cs:line 44
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Program.<CheckFooAndBar>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase\NLogAsyncExceptionTestCase.Console\Program.cs:line 30
```

My question is: Is there a (convenient, standard) way to convert this to a proper backtrace in the semantic sense, such as:

```
CheckFooAndBar
Foo
Bar
```

Of course there could be a mixture of awaits and inline path fragments in the stack.

I tried looking at the stack as it is with .NET 4.5 and SL5 with the async targetting pack, but not yet with WinRT. The output is from .NET 4.5.

In SL5, which is what I mainly do, the situation is more problematic: You don't get line numbers in stack traces in Silverlight (even with elevated privileges), which makes the need for context more important.

Comment: I'm not aware of any facilities like this. .NET 4.5 does support ETW tracing with enough detail that you could build an event listener to construct a stack trace like this. But that would be a lot of work and I don't think SL5 would support it anyway.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. But thanks for the comment, a negative is information also.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx.

Comment: I wrote up a "manual" solution [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). You do have to add code to each method you want to include, though. :(

Comment: Toni: please add your comment as answer.

Comment: Update: I released a [NuGet package (described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) that uses PostSharp to inject tracing automatically. So getting a good causality stack should be a lot simpler now. Unfortunately, SL is not supported, but if you can duplicate the error in a desktop app you could trace it easily.

Comment: Not directly a solution, but [here's a hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633192/868227) to get original method given async method.

Comment: John, what did you end up doing? I'm SL5 user myself..

Comment: @katit Sorry, didn't see your comment. But I don't really have a good answer for sl, which I still use - I usually set breakpoints and use logging so that I can reconstruct the semantic stack.

Comment: That's bad :( If error during debug - no problem. I'm more concerned about those I get in my logs and can't tell what caused it..

Comment: I suggest trying [Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier) which can create much more detailed stack traces for you.

Answer (score 7):

With Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.1, this problem appears to be addressed - and not only in .NET.

**Further Reading**: [Debugging Asynchronous Code in Visual Studio 2013 - Call Stack enhancements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-asynchronous-code-in-visual-studio-2013-call-stack-enhancements/).