# Serilog not logging as expected when using TextWriter

Tags: c#, serilog

I am trying to figure out how to get Serilog to log the class name and method/line number, like I would see with log4cxx in C++.

I tried my best to grab all the relevant bits out of the real code I am working on and come up with a minimal example.

I've also been Googling Serilog left and right, but I am not finding good documentation. I suppose it is because there are so many libraries on top of the base serilog and each needs there own docs to tell me how to do things.

I can see the basics on configuration at https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics , but this seems to use a TextWriter sink from a seperate Serilog library and a custom formatter, both of which I don't really understand.

I can also find examples on stack overflow that use the simple configuatation and the enrich call to log the class and method names.

[C# ASP.NET Core Serilog add class name and method to log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576733/c-sharp-asp-net-core-serilog-add-class-name-and-method-to-log?rq=1)

I am not able to get it to log them. How can I get this to log the class and method name or line number while still using the custom formatter and TextWriter?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Formatting;

namespace SerilogDemo {

    // Someone else made this, I just changed the name to protect the innocent
    public class SomeonesLogTextFormatter : ITextFormatter
    {
        public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(logEvent.Level);
            output.Write(": ");
            logEvent.MessageTemplate.Render(logEvent.Properties, output);
            output.WriteLine();

            if (logEvent.Exception != null)
            {
                output.WriteLine(logEvent.Exception);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private Serilog.ILogger _log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<SomeClass>();

        public SomeClass()
        {
            _log.Debug("SomeClass has been instantiated");
        }

        public void Foo()
        {
            _log.Debug("Foo has been called");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.TextWriter(textWriter: Console.Out, formatter: new SomeonesLogTextFormatter())
                .CreateLogger();

            var poop = new SomeClass();
            poop.Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Serilog way of adding more information to a log message is by adding properties to the `LogContext` either manually or by using an Enricher that does that for you. Read more about [Serilog Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

Serilog by default does not capture that information, and that can be quite expensive if you do for every single message, but the way to do it is by using [C#'s Caller Information feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) such as `CallerMemberName`, `CallerFilePath`, `CallerLineNumber`.

[Here is an example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cbdabner/b2c921a3a6da05cdb946/raw/e8032f77c836e1af28ff4b5ffe8916a8df7ff739/SerilogWithCallerAttributes.cs), also copied below:

```
public static class SerilogWithCallerAttributes
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
            .CreateLogger();

        GoDoSomething();
    }

    public static void GoDoSomething()
    {
        int score = 12;

        Log.Information("Player scored: {Score}", CallerInfo.Create(), score);
    }
}

public static class Log
{
    public static void Information(string messageTemplate, CallerInfo callerInfo, params object[] propertyValues)
    {
        Serilog.Log.Logger
            .ForHere(callerInfo.CallerFilePath, callerInfo.CallerMemberName, callerInfo.CallerLineNumber)
            .Information(messageTemplate, propertyValues);
    }
}

public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILogger ForHere(
        this ILogger logger,
        [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
        [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = 0)
    {
        return logger
            .ForContext("SourceFile", callerFilePath)
            .ForContext("SourceMember", callerMemberName)
            .ForContext("SourceLine", callerLineNumber);
    }
}

public class CallerInfo
{
    public string CallerFilePath { get; private set; }

    public string CallerMemberName { get; private set; }

    public int CallerLineNumber { get; private set; }

    private CallerInfo(string callerFilePath, string callerMemberName, int callerLineNumber)
    {
        this.CallerFilePath = callerFilePath;
        this.CallerMemberName = callerMemberName;
        this.CallerLineNumber = callerLineNumber;
    }

    public static CallerInfo Create(
        [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
        [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = 0)
    {
        return new CallerInfo(callerFilePath, callerMemberName, callerLineNumber);
    }
}
```